# Angular 5 + Polymer: Styles of Polymer components with and without Origami

Tags: bower, angular5, polymer-2.x

I'm working on an Angular 5 project (which I generated with the Angular CLI), using Bower for front-end dependencies. All the dependencies I need for my project are custom polymer components. I originally was able to get this project to work by using the [Origami](https://github.com/hotforfeature/origami) project, however I'm finding that I'd rather not use the project if possible since Polymer 2 and Angular 5 are meant to work quite well together now. The only place I've used the Origami project is in app.module.ts, where I import the PolymerModule from @codebakery/origami like so:

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { PolymerModule } from '@codebakery/origami';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AnalysisComponent } from './analysis/analysis.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

import { SemtkService } from './services/semtk.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AnalysisComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, 
    FormsModule,
    PolymerModule.forRoot() // Only import .forRoot() once and at the highest level

  ],
  providers: [ SemtkService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In trying to delete the origami project, I've commented out the line `PolymerModule.forRoot(),` from the imports array. When I do this, the Polymer components seem to loose their styling.

Here is the page WITH the `PolymerModule.forRoot()` import:

[page WITH import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u60el.png)

And here is the page WITHOUT the import:

[page WITHOUT import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9TNN.png)

Any ideas about what I could do to fix this would be welcome - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Author of Origami here, there's a service the library provides at the application root that registers Angular component styles with ShadyCSS (needed for @apply mixin support for all browsers and custom properties for browsers that don't support them).

https://github.com/hotforfeature/origami/blob/v2/origami/src/style/shared-styles-host.ts

You could either include that one service and provide it at your app's root, or write your own service that does something similar. Once Angular's styles are registered with ShadyCSS, any variables/mixins you define in Angular will be applied in Polymer.